# Why is css3 translate not working here?

Tags: html, css

Trying to make a css3 cube I started with this..

```
 <div class="box">
      <div class="left"></div>
      <div class="front"></div>
      <div class="right"></div>
      <div class="back"></div>
 </div>
```

css:

```
 .box {
 position: relative;
 top: 300px;
 left: 300px;
 width: 300px;
 height: 300px;
 }

 .left {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 background: #ff4d4d;
 height: 300px;
 width: 300px;
 transform: translate(-300px, 0px) rotateY(80deg);
 -webkit-transform: translate(-300px, 0px) rotateY(80deg);
 -moz-transform: translate(-300px, 0px) rotateY(80deg);
 -o-transform: translate(-300px, 0px) rotateY(80deg);
 z-index: 1;
 }

 .front {
 background: #ff6b6b;
 height: 300px;
 width: 300px;
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 }
```

I've made a fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/E9Q7w/..
What's going on here is that the rotate is applying, and the translate does push the box in the X axis. But the rotation axis/centre is not pushed. It's still in the middle of the box. like translate is not doing what it's suppose to be doing, right? why is that? what am I missing?

Comment: It seems to me that this is working perfectly. The `transform-origin` is at the centre by default and you're not changing it, so why expect it to move?

Comment: Yeah, thx. I was confusing translate with transform origin property. cuz in this css3 generator http://www.css3-generator.de/transform.html translate seemed to change transform origins.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong values. `rotateX` and `rotateY` don't exist. If you want to select where to rotate it from, use `transform-origin:`, `transform-origin-(x/y/z)`

```
transform: translate(-300px, 0px) rotate(80deg);
-webkit-transform: translate(-300px, 0px) rotate(80deg);
-moz-transform: translate(-300px, 0px) rotate(80deg);
-o-transform: translate(-300px, 0px) rotate(80deg);
```

Here are some docs on `transform-origin` - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-origin